# SQL Server 2019 Express date

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a column in my SQL Server Express table configured with a `date` datatype.

When I edit the table and enter 7-1-2022 into the date column, it displays 2022-07-01.

How can I get the column to show its contents as `MM-DD-YYYY`? I'd like this behavior to apply to all tables in the database. Thanks.

Comment: You don't. Date and time data types, like `date` are binary values; they have no format. The format *presented* to the user is defined by the application. Define the format you want for your dates in the presentation layer of your application.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My 'application' is a third-party SCADA package that retrieves database values. I haven't found a way to manipulate the date format at that end. I had hoped there might have been something like setting the database Default Language that might have helped.

Comment: No, there is no setting in the database, the setting should be in the application.

Comment: You can do `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), YourValue, 110)` but I would advise to try and change the presentation layer.

Comment: In re: third-party SCADA, are these tables in a database provided by the vendor? If so, it works as is - no need to change anything.